# DaVinci Resolve on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't start

Tags: 18.04

I can't run Resolve on my Ubuntu 18.04LTE, after running Resolve i can only see some output:

/opt/resolve/bin/resolve

```
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
16.0b (#033) Linux/Clang
Main thread starts: 2D79EB00
[0x7fd42d79eb00] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-06-20 10:32:46,970 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0x7fd42d79eb00] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-06-20 10:32:46,971 | Loaded log config from /home/my_account/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/configs/log-conf.xml
[0x7fd42d79eb00] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-06-20 10:32:46,971 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[5]    22674 abort (core dumped)  /opt/resolve/bin/resolve
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Hi! Did you end up figuring out how to solve this issue?

Comment: Typically some kind of graphics card / NVIDIA driver trouble. Resolve needs a NVIDIA card plus original NVIDIA drivers including Cuda.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to install DaVince Resolve 16 on the Ubuntu 18.04 and came across the same problem.

The solution was to create this link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /usr/lib64
```

Comment: Nope. Not the solution, at least for me